# How to use TheIntern with Webpack and Babel

Tags: webpack, intern

I try to use [theintern](https://theintern.io/) to make my Units/Fonctionals Tests, but I use webpack for bundling/loading modules, webpack-dev-server for local developement and babel for transpilling JS.

When I try to load a component I have error from a file who are imported by an import in my component.

```
// a.js
const getWindowLocation = window.location
export default getWindowLocation

// b.js
import getWindowLocation from "a.js"
const anotherVar = getWindowLocation
// make some work with anotherVar
export default anotherVar

// c.js
import anotherVar from "b.js"
// module i try to test
const something = somevalue
export default something
```

Then in my test file :

```
// test.c.js
import something from "c.js"
```

But, when i load my test suite i have an error like :

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
at getWindowLocation  <a.js>
at Object.<anonymous>  <b.js>
```

I use jsdom to enable `window`and it's work for `c.js` but not for other module.

So, how to configure theintern to handle modules from webpack without SystemJS and Typescript ?

Comment: Could you post your project (or an example project) somewhere? The `window` error suggests there may be a configuration issue somewhere. You could also look at the Intern [webpack example](https://github.com/theintern/intern-examples/tree/master/webpack-example) if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
I will try to make an example.

I have already looked at the example of webpack, but it uses webpack to build its test files, not those of the project [Webpack Entry point](https://github.com/theintern/intern-examples/blob/master/webpack-example/webpack.config.ts#L6). Local files are handle with underscore and backbone in the [index.html](https://github.com/theintern/intern-examples/blob/master/webpack-example/index.html#L53-L56)

Comment: Hi,

I have make this small example : https://github.com/ethyde/test-theintern-webpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `c.js` assumes `window` is in the global scope. While `createwindow.js` creates a jsdom window, it doesn't add it to the global scope.

One solution is to add jsdom's `window` to the global scope:

```
// createwindow.js
const jsdom = require('jsdom')
const { JSDOM } = jsdom
const { window } = new JSDOM()
global.window = window;
```

However, as the jsdom authors point out, this [isn't a good practice](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/wiki/Don%27t-stuff-jsdom-globals-onto-the-Node-global). Instead, your test class should use your `createWindow` plugin to get `window`:

```
// c.js
const window = intern.getPlugin('createWindow');
const getWindowLocation = window.location
export default getWindowLocation
```

Comment: I made the changes in my test file : https://github.com/ethyde/test-theintern-webpack/blob/master/tests/unit/a.test.js and yes, it's work, but, so I can not use `import()` anymore ?

Comment: You can use `import` (if you have something to import that gives you a `window` reference) or `getPlugin`. The issue was just that you weren't getting a reference to `window` in `c.js`.

Comment: I accepted the answer because it actually works, but I'm not sure to right understand it.
In your examples: 
*the first works, but it's a bad practice, and seems options such as [Run code before tests start](https://github.com/theintern/intern/blob/master/docs/how_to.md#run-code-before-tests-start), or plugins are not very useful in this context ?
*the second suggests using `intern` in a production file?
I am a beginner in Unit Testing and I try to understand the good way.
thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand that `c.js` was production. You should definitely not use Intern there. :) In any case, the core issue is still that you're running browser code in Node. Jsdom is one way to do that. Adding the jsdom window to the global namespace is one way to use jsdom. It's not _ideal_, because your browser-based code will be running in a strange environment (Node's global space contains properties that browsers don't have), so you could end up with code that passes tests but won't work in a real browser. However, it's the easiest way to use jsdom with Intern right now.